# How to share something on Google plus Via ios app

Tags: google-plus, ios7.1

hi I wanna share something on Google + via my ios app. I could find the way for Facebook and Twitter. But couldnt find any tutorial for Google plus.

Can anybody provide me a better tutorial for this google plus sharing in ios 7

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/ for complete and official information for how to do this.

Comment: Update: The google plus sign in is deprecate now. Use Google sign in and to share to google plus, refer to this: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share